# Pythonでデータフレーム名に対して繰り返しの処理を行うには？

Tags: python, pandas

複数のデータフレームがあり、それぞれのデータフレームの大きさを知りたく、次のようなコードを書いています。

```
dfs =['df_a', 'df_b', 'df_c']

for df_name in dfs:
　　print(df_name)
    df_name.shape
```

df_nameが、文字列であり、.shapeは使えないというエラーが出てきます（その通りなのですが）。

```
'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

どのようにすれば、データフレームについて、繰り返しの処理を行えるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

データフレームの名前とインスタンスを dictで管理すると良いのではないでしょうか

```
dfs = {'df_a':df_a, 'df_b':df_b, 'df_c':df_c}
for name, df in dfs.items():
    print(name)
    print(df.shape)
```

Comment: ご回答をありがとうございます。dfsの書き方に問題があったこと、よく分かりました。

Answer (score 1):

データフレームであれば、そのままprint(df_a.shape)でサイズがわかります。

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(index =[1,1], columns=["a","b"])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(index =[1,1], columns=["a","b"])
df_c = pd.DataFrame(index =[1,1], columns=["a","b"])

dfs = [df_a, df_b, df_c]

for df_names in dfs:
    print(df_names.shape)
```

リストに入れる前にデータフレームを作成して、それをリストに入れるだけです。
例では適当なデータフレームを作成してます。
質問のリストはただの文字列になっているようなので、Pandasの.shapeが作用しません。使おうとしているメソッドが正しい型のものを参照しているのか注意すると、原因が導きやすくなります。

参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答をありがとうございます。dfsの書き方の多様性を、理解できました。コメントもありがとうございます。2つのご回答をベストアンサーとできないのが残念です。