# 複数データフレームの行数を一気にカウントする方法

Tags: python, pandas

Pythonのfor文について質問させてください。（初歩的な質問で恐縮です、、）

以下の４つのデータフレームがあったとします。それぞれのデータフレームの行数を、for文を使って一気にカウントしたいです。
df_1
df_2
df_3
df_4

データフレームが１つだった場合は、以下のよう記述できると思います。
print(len(df_1))

これを、for文で４つのファイルに回す場合、以下のような記述ができるのかと思いましたが。思うような結果が返ってきません、、。

for i in range(1,5):
    print(len('df_' + str(i)))

考え方が誤っていますでしょうか？？お気づきの点がありましたらアドバイスいただけると幸いです。

Comment: `len('df_' + str(i))` の部分の `'df_' + str(i)` はデータフレームではなくて文字列になります。なので、`df_1` や `df_2` といった文字列の長さ(文字数)が表示されることになります。

Comment: なるほど、、この記述方法ではデータフレームの行数カウントはできないということですね。。for文でなくても構わないのですが、複数データフレームをそれぞれ一気に行数カウントする方法をご存知でしたら教えていただきたいです！

Comment: [この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/53236/16894)が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: まさに同じ問題でした。。とても参考になりました。ありがとうございます！